# Find the probability that two persons are grouped in the same team

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A group of 9 people was further divided into 3 teams of three persons. How do you find the probability that 2 persons (let's name them `person A` and `person B`) are in the same group?

I think this is similar to the word permutation problem wherein two letters must be right next to each other, so you just treat them as one.

What I would do is treat `person A` and `person B` as one person and continue in grouping them, but there is a special case that only in the group of this new person can there be only 2 persons and not 3 (since that new person represents two).

Using the combination formula: $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

\begin{align*}
&= \dfrac{9!}{3!(9-3)!}\\
&= \dfrac{9!}{3!\cdot6!}\\
&= 84
\end{align*}

This is clearly wrong since it is not taking into account the fact that I am treating two persons as one.

Comment: What did you try? Show your attempts.

Comment: OK but what did you try?

Comment: I updated my post. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ gets into any of the teams, there are still two places in the same team.

The probability of $B$ getting into one of those two places out of remaining $8$ people $ = \displaystyle \frac{2}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Or you can think of it as below -

$A$ and $B$ can be together in any of the $3$ teams and whichever team they are on, there is just one slot in the team where $1$ from rest of the $7$ people can get in.

So, desired probability $ \displaystyle = \frac{{3 \choose 1} \times {2 \choose 2 } \times {7 \choose 1} }{9 \choose 3} = \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with your route of grouping $A$ and $B$ as only one person that has the problem that you've found, try to start with calculating all possibilities of teams and all possibilities with $A$ and $B$ joined.

Always with this kind of problems it's useful to start with something small that you can manually write and check. Say that we want to divide 4 people into two groups. We have a total of $\frac{4!}{2!2!2!}$ possibilities. This is because we can rearrange people from the same team (so we need to divide by $2!2!$, one $2!$ for each team) but we also don't care about the order of the teams, so we can rearrange them too, that's why there are three $2!$ in the denominator. A total of $3$ possibilities. If you force $A$ and $B$ to be together, there is only one possibility for them to be together, so the total probability is $1/3$.

Try to repeat this process but with $9$ people and $3$ teams.

Comment: For this case, that would mean $\dfrac{9!}{3!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!}$?

Comment: @muw There are three teams now. You can rearrange the three people from each team, which will give you that expression. But you can also rearrange the teams themselves, so you're missing one term there.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot follow, do you mean $\dfrac{9!}{3!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!\cdot3!}$?

Comment: @muw Yes, that would be the total possibilities of teams. Think again in the small case: we have two $2!$ because $AB$ is the same team than $BA$ and there are two teams. We had an additional $2!$ because creating two teams as in $AB, CD$ is the same than $CD, AB$, so we had three $2!$. Now there are three teams, for each one we have a $3!$ in the denominator. We have an additional $3!$ because we can reorder the teams as we like $ABC, DEF, GHI$ is the same than $DEF, GHI, ABC$ and so on, so we end up with four $3!$ in the denominator.

Comment: @muw Now you only need to compute the total possibilities where $A$ and $B$ are in the same team.

Comment: How would you translate that mathematically? Currently, if we get the result of $\dfrac{9!}{3!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!}$, we get 280.

Comment: @muw There are seven choices you have for the third person in the team. After that, you have to count all the ways we can do two teams with the six people remaining, we can apply the same process. $6$ people ($6!$) into two teams ($2!$ in the denominator) of three each (two $3!$ in the denominator). So $7 \frac{6!}{2!3!3!}$, which gives us $70$ choices. The probability is $1/4$. You can take a look at the other answer for another method. It's important that you understand each step in whatever method you end up using, though.